# Launching an application with an user environment

Tags: environment-variables

If I launch `eclipse` from the command line, the application is aware of the environment variables of the user (e.g. PYTHONPATH) and sets up the interpreter accordingly with `Auto Config`. This is not the case if I launch an application with a GUI icon or an application launcher. If my application launcher supports scripting, is there a way for me to specify which user's environment to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think replacing `/path/to/executable` in your program launcher with

```
sh 'exec /path/to/executable'
```

should do the trick. `sh` is meant to represent your target shell: modify *ad lib*.

I'm assuming here that your user account is the one that creates the `PYTHONPATH` variable. Unless you're root or have properly configured sudo access, you are not allowed to clone the environment of another user.

Comment: I was using an external bash script. And it had the basic system env's (e.g. USER, HOME), but not the ones I defined in `.bashrc` I was able to get the environment variables by manually adding it to the script. I could have sourced `.bashrc`, but I deemed it unnecessary.